# Linear Regression using a Neural Network

Tags: neural-networks

I am trying to create a regression model using a Neural Network. I am currently learning how to work with neural networks (deeplearning.ai) and so the model is not implemented using any existing frameworks like keras.

Based on what I have learned,

- the model is configured to use no activation function in the output
  layer (which, obviously, has only one node).
- Input is images of fashion articles (shirt, jackets etc).
- output predicts prices for input article images.
- Hidden layers all use ReLU.
- Random initialization is done for all weights.
- Cost function is Mean Squared Error:
  $$J = \frac{1}{2m}\sum_{i=1}^m (a^{(i)} - y^{(i)})^2$$

Based on the formula for backpropogation, the last layer should get the error based on cost function. For a single example, we have:
$$ \mathcal L =  \frac{1}{2}(a - y)^2 $$
$$ error = \frac{d\mathcal L}{da} = (a - y) $$

where `L` is the loss function, `a` is the predicted value and `y` is the actual price of the article.

For the entire training set, we have (vectorized):
$$ error = \frac{d\mathcal L}{dA} = (A - Y) $$
where `m` is the number of examples,  `A, Y` are `(1 * m)` vectors where each value corresponds to each single example. `A` contains `m` predictions and `Y` has all the `m` prices.

Is this `error` value correct?

My problem is that the model converges to a what appears to be a local minima. The error after a few 100 iterations gets stuck. The error is also not very small (~ 0.0005). I am not sure if I have the equations right.

Comment: Note that this question may be better at home on either of [stats.SE], [scicomp.SE], or [ai.SE]. Do you want us to migrate it?

Comment: @Raphael, if you think it'd be better suited then yes, please. That would be great.

Comment: Do you really mean a *linear* regression model, or do you mean a regression model?  Neural networks are non-linear (unless you limit them severely -- e.g., one layer, no activation function, etc., and at that point it's no longer reasonable to call it a neural network).

Comment: Please define all notation.  What is $a$?  What is $y$?

Comment: @D.W. I have added definitions. I do mean a regression model. From what I have learned, using something like a sigmoid function in the output layer would restrict the output to (0, 1). Not using any activation would prevent that and output continuous values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  This is not the correct way to train such a network.  To update the network, we want to update the weights of the network.  Thus instead of using $\frac{d\mathcal L}{dA}$ to update the weights, you should be using $\frac{d\mathcal L}{dW}$, where $W$ are the weights.  This could be computed as

$$\frac{d\mathcal L}{dW} = \frac{d\mathcal L}{dA} \times \frac{d\mathcal A}{dW},$$

where $\frac{d\mathcal L}{dA}$ is computed using the formula you obtained ($\frac{d\mathcal L}{dA} = A-Y$ is correct), and where $\frac{d\mathcal A}{dW}$ is computed using backpropagation through the network.

Or, better yet, use an existing framework that performs automatic differentiation for you (e.g., Keiras, Tensorflow), and save yourself a lot of effort.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using the above mentioned equation to update weights. My question was whether I was using the correct derivative for loss function w.r.t. `A`. If it is indeed correct then what would be the next thing to check? I am using about a 100 images for input and about a 1000 iterations. Do you think adding more data and increasing number of iterations would help?

Comment: @abhink, sorry, I don't know.  In my experience, open-ended debugging questions don't work well in our site format here.